# $B = \{x \in Q :0<x<1\}$ is not open

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that $B = \{x \in Q :0<x<1\}$ is not open?

I know I can that if I take $x\in B$ any $\epsilon$ neighborhood of $x$ will contain a real not in B, but how can I show this?

Comment: Every open interval contains irrational numbers.

Comment: Not open *among which* superset?  The Rationals, or the Reals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in(0,1)$, the sequence $a_n = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} + x$ convergences to $x$ as $n\to\infty$. If $x$ is rational, $a_n$ is a sequence of irrationals. Can you complete the proof from here?

Answer (score 0):

Take $x=\frac{1}{2}$ and arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, define $N_\epsilon (x)=\{x-\{1}{2},x+\frac {1}{2}\}$, what we want to show here is that $N_\epsilon (x)\notsubseteq \mathbb{Q} $.
This is obvious since $N_\epsilon(x)$ contains at least $r$ an irrational number hence $N_\epsilon (x)\notsubseteq\mathbb {Q} $, and we're done.